# Angular - Insert Dynamic Form Content to Database in Zeppelin

Tags: mysql, angularjs, apache-zeppelin, openzeppelin

I am trying to create a simple dynamic form in Apache Zeppelin using Angular interpreter. I want to pass those values which are coming as input from the form in one notebook to a dynamic MySQL insert query in another notebook. Angular code as given below:

```
<form>
  1) Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
  </br></br>
  2) Give a rating for pack:
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="Good">Good
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="Average">Average
  <input type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="Bad">Bad
  </br></br>
  3) Select a Region:
  <select ng-model="reg">
    <option value="">
    <option value="KNZ">KNZ
    <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng
    <option value="NorthEast">NorthEast
  </select>
</form>
```

[This will create a dynamic form Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLiL.png)
I want to execute an insert query(MySQL) in the next paragraph accessing the above variables "firstname", "myVar" and "reg" from angular dynamic form.

```
insert into Table (Firstname,Rating,Region) values ("firstname","myVar","reg")
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ZeppelinContext` variables directly in jdbc interpreter by setting `zeppelin.jdbc.interpolation` property of the jdbc interpreter to 'true'

Example: `%jdbc select * from test where country = '{country_code}'`

Refer this [link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/jdbc.html#object-interpolation) for more info

Comment: @SaravanElumalai Thank you. The link was really helpful. But my doubt is Dynamic form will be created only once i run the above angular code in a paragraph. In that form i will add the new variables then how the binding of angular variables will happen without executing anything.